# Authenticating Firebase Facebook Token in REST / GraphQL

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, graphql, facebook-login

I followed this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login

token is a new accessToken given from the client

```
const context = ({req}) => {
      const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token)

  try {
    firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

but I'm receiving this error (100% sure the token is copied correctly)

```
{ [Error: Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.]
  code: 'auth/invalid-api-key',
  message:
   'Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.' }
{ _extensionStack:
   GraphQLExtensionStack { extensions: [ [CacheControlExtension] ] } }
```

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

On the client side I had to change the facebook accessToken into an IdToken via:

```
getIdToken = async () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
    const result = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)

    const IdToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
}
```

Then verify the IdToken in the backend

```
try {
    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
    console.log(decodedToken)
  } catch (error) {
    // error code
  }
```